# Gibberish / malformed negative y-axis values in plotly charts in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

Im trying to plot a bar plot in plotly that is representing net-gains (will have positive and negative bar values). But somewhat the negative values in the y-axis are being represented in gibberish. I tried several things, including using `update_layout` function, but nothing seems to work. Im using the `make_subplots` function because i want to plot multiple viz on one figure.

Im using databricks for this code.
Attaching my code and viz output:

```
net_gains = pd.DataFrame()
net_gains["general_net_gain"] = [-2,2,-1,2]


fig = plotly.subplots.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)
fig.add_bar(x=net_gains.index, y=net_gains["general_net_gain"], row=1, col=1)
fig.update_layout(height=400,width=500,showlegend=True)
```

[image: Viz output]

Comment: It works very well with me without any gibberish output for negative values

Comment: Please try to add the original code

Comment: @Hamzah this is the original code, im using databricks for this code so it my be related to the reason its not working?

Comment: Try to check out the values of `net_gains["general_net_gain"]`

Comment: I tried running this in databricks and I cannot reproduce your error. what happens if you restart your databricks notebook? also what version of plotly are you using?

Comment: @DerekO im using Plotly version 5.12.0

Comment: @Hamzah The values of ```net_gains["general_net_gain"]``` are floats and ints.

Comment: What type of encoding is set on your device? What OS are you working with? I'm going to guess that what is used for the negative sign is encoded incorrectly. I can't imagine that it is an endash or emdash, as Python wouldn't interpret it as values, either.

Comment: @Kat when i reverted my plotly version back to ```5.7.0``` from ```5.12.0``` everything worked fine.

Comment: I'm seeing the same gibberish labels intsead of a `-` sign on MacOS with Plotly 5.12.0 in my code. But very oddly if I run the example above then I don't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add scripts from [GitHub](https://github.com/LayTec-AG/Plotly.Blazor)

plotly-latest.min.js
plotly-interop.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35349479)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I added this line to the html file :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Python code :

```
import plotly.offline as offline

config = dict({
    'scrollZoom': True,
    'displayModeBar': True,
    'editable': False
})

template = """
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<body style="background-color:#111111;">
</head>
<body>
{plot_div:s}
</body>""".format(plot_div=offline.plot(your_plotly_fig, config=config, output_type='div'))

with open('fig.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    fp.write(template)
```